# File path is not supported

Tags: c#

```
string fil = @"‪D:\\vish1_vish.txt";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(File, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
```

In this line I'm getting file path name is unsupported. Please help me how to rectify this error.

Comment: You pass "File" not "fil" to the FileStream ctor

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing your path to the method:

```
string fil = @"‪D:\vish1_vish.txt"; 
FileStream fs = new FileStream(File, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
```

I guess it should be something like this(your question is quite unclear):

```
string fil = @"‪D:\vish1_vish.txt"; 
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fil, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: string fil = @"‪D:\vish1_vish.txt";                                                    FileStream fs=newFileStream(fil,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);I'm getting error as unsupported file format